# What's better: Test if event handler is bound or use .off() directly

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have a situation in which we are faced with event handlers being bound to an element multiple times (due to a third party module).

We can work around this by making sure to only add the event handler if it is not already present. Another possibility is to simply remove all event handlers before adding it.

Which solution is the preferred one? Is there any major difference in terms of performance?

```
function hasEventHandler(element, event) {
    var ev = $._data(element, 'events');
    return (ev && ev[event]) ? true : false;
}

if ( !hasEventHandler($('#element')[0], 'click') ) {
    $('#element').on('click', function () {
        // do something
        console.log('clicked');
    });
}
```

OR

```
$('#element')
    .off
    .on('click', function () {
    // do something
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a [namespaced event](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names) with `.off()` because if there is some other click handler added by some other code it is prone to bugs

```
$('#element')
    .off('click.me')
    .on('click.me', function () {
    // do something
    console.log('clicked');
});
```